# Reading tokens from a file in C

Tags: c, file, token

I'm trying to read tokens from a file and place them in an array. I'm doing this in multiple steps, starting with figuring out how many tokens are in the file so i can estimate how large I need to the array to be. I was able to accomplish this using the `getline()` function.

```
FILE *crack, *dic;
crack = fopen(crack_file, "r");
dic = fopen(dic_file, "r");

char *lineptr;
size_t n;

int dic_word_count, crack_word_count, crack_line_count;
dic_word_count = crack_word_count = crack_line_count = 1;

while(getline(&lineptr, &n, dic) != EOF)
{
    dic_word_count++;
}

char **dictionary = malloc(8*dic_word_count);
```

but when I try to do the same thing with a different file

```
while(getline(&lineptr,&n, crack) != EOF)
{
    crack_line_count++;
}
printf("%d",crack_line_count);
```

the print statement is never reached. I'm really not sure what is going on and I'm just wondering if anybody has any ideas of what's happening and a possible fix. Let me know if you'd like to see more of my code, I'm trying to keep this concise but thorough. thanks in advance.

Comment: And you tested this in a debugger, right? What happens when you actually print the line and its length *in* the second while-loop? What happens when you strip out the code using that `dictionary` allocation and just move from one file loop to another? In short, what steps, if *any*, have you taken to actually *debug* this?

Comment: @WhozCraig I've narrowed the issue down to this part of the code because when I comment it out(archaic as it may seem) every thing else works fine. When I run it through gdb I get a segmentation fault at the first while loop, which i don't get when I comment out the second loop.

Comment: You really should get into the habit of *checking return codes*. If one of your `FILE*` is `NULL`, you won't notice until your program segaults. Also, it's not good style to assume that `EOF` is `-1`, as in your check for `getline` returning an error/eof condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`line` needs to be initialized before the call to `getline()` and ...

> `getline()` returns -1 on failure to read a line (including end-of-file condition).     In the event of an error, errno is set to indicate the cause.".

Use -1 as `EOF` is not necessarily -1.

[Ref](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html)

```
char *lineptr = NULL;
size_t n = 0;
...
while(getline(&lineptr, &n, dic) != -1)
```

Note: robust code would use

```
size_t dic_word_count, crack_word_count, crack_line_count;
... 
printf("%zu", crack_line_count);
```

Answer (score 0):

Problems that I see:

1. `getline` is not a standard C library function. I don't know which platform you are using and what the expectations are as far as memory allocation and deallocation. I would strongly suggest use of the standard C library function [`fgets`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/).
2. If `getline` expects a pointer to pre-allocated memory, then there is a problem since you are not allocating any memory. If `getline` allocates memory, you need have code to deallocate that memory. I see a problem either way.
3. You are incrementing `dic_word_count` for each line you are reading and then using `8*dic_word_count` in the call to `malloc`. Are you assuming something that translates to `8`?